# C++: std::vector [] operator

Tags: c++, stl, std, stdvector

Why `std::vector` has 2 operators `[]` realization?

```
reference       operator[](size_type pos);
const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
```

Comment: You can't see those differences, right up there in your post?

Comment: [maintaining const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-overloading.html). What if you only had access to a constant std::vector<> object? How could you correctly access an element without the second method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One for *non-const* vector object, and the other for *const* vector object.

```
void f(std::vector<int> & v1, std::vector<int> const & v2)
{
   //v1 is non-const vector
   //v2 is const vector

   auto & x1 = v1[0]; //invokes the non-const version
   auto & x2 = v2[0]; //invokes the const version

   v1[0] = 10; //okay : non-const version can modify the object
   v2[0] = 10; //compilation error : const version cannot modify 

   x1 = 10; //okay : x1 is inferred to be `int&`
   x2 = 10; //error: x2 is inferred to be `int const&`
}
```

As you can see, the non-const version lets you modify the vector element using index, while the `const` version does NOT let you modify the vector elements. That is the semantic difference between these two versions.

For more detail explanation, see this FAQ:

- [The Rule of Thumb: Subscript operators often come in pairs!](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-overloading.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it is not helpful to simply tell people to 'read a book' or 'google' - I'm sure the majority of questions could be answered that way. It's a legitimate question and he got a quick and concise answer, with an example.

Comment: @Brett: We expect some level of basic effort and research to be put in before asking questions. And did you see me suggesting that this question shouldn't have been asked, or any close votes? No.

Answer (score 1):

To make this differentiation possible:

```
// const vector object, cannot be modified
// const operator[] allows for this
int get_value(const std::vector<int>& vec, size_t index)
{
   return vec[index];
}

// non-const vector object can be modified
// non-const operator[] allows for this
void set_value(std::vector<int>& vec, size_t index, int val)
{
   vec[index] = value;
}

std::vector<int> values;
values.push_back(10);
values.push_back(20);

set_value(values, 0, 50);
get_value(values, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

one so that you can modify and read from a (non const) vector

```
void foo( std::vector<int>& vector )
{
    // reference operator[]( size_type );
    int old = vector[0];
    vector[0] = 42;
}
```

one so that you can read from a const vector

```
void foo( std::vector<int> const& vector )
{
    //const_reference operator[]( size_type ) const;
    int i = vector[0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the two overloads allows you to retrieve a `const` reference to an element of a vector accessed through a `const` variable. The other one allows you to obtain a non-`const` reference to an element of a vector accessed through a non-`const` variable.

If you didn't have the `const` version, you wouldn't be allowed to compile the following for instance:

```
void f(vector<int> const& v)
{
    cout << v[0]; // Invokes the const version of operator []
}
```

In the following example, instead, the non-const version is invoked, which returns a non-`const` reference to the first element in the array and allow, for instance, to assign a new value to it:

```
void f(vector<int>& v)
{
    v[0] = 1; // Invokes the non-const version of operator[]
}
```